# How to construct a LinkedList using a for-each loop in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list, readability

I'm trying to figure out a way to construct a LinkedList with a for-each loop.

I've put the way I currently have it and it works.  I just find it to be very ugly, since I have to declare a single listNode outside the loop and the rest inside a for loop.  I just can't shake the feeling this is a clumsy solution.

How It's written-

```
private listNode nameList;

public listManager(ArrayList<String> names) {
    nameList = new listNode(names.get(0));
    listNode current = nameList;
    for (int i = 1;  i < names.size(); i++) {
        current.next = new listNode(names.get(i));
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

I want to use a for-each loop and make everything just a bit more readable but I get the problem of trying to get current.next when current is null so I get a nullpointerexception.  Any ideas?

How I would like it would ideally like it written but doesn't work-

```
listNode current = nameList;
for (String person : names) {
    current.next = new listNode(person);
    current = current.next;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: If you want to use an enhanced `for` loop i.e. a `foreach` then you should do the `null` check inside it.

Comment: So just add a null check inside the loop to account for the case of adding the first node??  I like it!  That never crossed my mind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my comment:

If you want to use an enhanced for loop i.e. a foreach then you should do the null check inside it.

```
nameList = null;
listNode current = null;
for (String person : names) {
    if (nameList= null) {
        nameList = new listNode(names.get(0));
        current = nameList;
    } else {
        current.next = new listNode(person);
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Another recommendation: use CamelCase for your class names for better code readability, `listNode` class should be `ListNode` and `listManager` class should be `ListManager`.

---

By @corsiKa's comment, this *won't be* a best suited case to use an enhanced `for` loop (in fact, this really depends on how many items we're talking about to measure the performance impact, but that's outside of this question). To make it a more generic algorithm that can even supports `List` (the generic interface implemented by `ArrayList`), you can use an `Iterator` instead:

```
Iterator<String> iterNames = names.iterator();
if (iterNames.hasNext()) {
    nameList = new listNode(iterNames.next());
    listNode current = nameList;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        current.next = new listNode(iterNames.next());
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Note that if you still want to stick with the enhanced `for` loop approach, there's no way to remove the `null` check from it.

Comment: There's no need to check it for null every time. You know it will be null when you start.

Comment: @corsiKa note that this is an enhanced `for` loop, so you don't know where you start or end as in the first OP's approach.

Comment: I just find this approach to be must more readable than the initial solution.  Yes you check for null every iteration but the readability is much better I think.  Thanks Luiggi!

Comment: @TimmayB answer updated using `Iterator` to avoid the `null` check in the enhanced `for` loop.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go about it if you want to generalize it to support `List` instead of `RandomAccess`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (int i = names.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
     person = new ListNode(names.get(i), person);
  }
```

going backward makes it much easier

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1

Without having your full code to compile (which might be more than necessary anyway) it's difficult to debug. One thing to note is your two loops are not identical.

The first does this:

```
for (int i = 1;  i < names.size(); i++) {
```

The second does this

```
for (String person : names) {
```

Which is essentially the same as

```
for (int i = 0;  i < names.size(); i++) {
    String person = names.get(i);
```

Note that **your** loop starts at **1** but the **generated** loops starts at **0**.

### Problem 2

That aside, your problem is most likely that your second part of code doesn't seem to create a new node for your header node (`namesList`).

### The solution

This is not an appropriate place to use an enhanced for loop. Enhanced for loops should only be used when identical operations will be applied to every element in your structure. In this case, you treat the first one as a special case, which complicates code. Your first loop, the one starting at 1, is the ideal way to solve this problem.

Comment: For problem 1- The whole reason I posted this question is because of this problem.  I want them to do the same thing but the for loop is different from the foreach loop.  For problem 2- Yes that's why I'm asking the question on here.

Comment: @TimmayB See my edit. This is not a good candidate to use an enhanced for loop.

Comment: @corsiKa even if *not a good candidate for enhanced `for` loop*, using `List#get` is not the bests candidate either =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes it is. You're passed in an `ArrayList`, which has constant time access.

Comment: @corsiKa that can should to a `List` for better design (but that's currently off topic of the question) and by doing it `List#get` won't be the best option to use.

Comment: @Luiggi You're absolutely right that if you change the scenario the best option also changes.

Comment: If a Foreach loop isn't ideal for this situation what would you suggest as a better way?

Comment: @TimmayB I wouldn't. Your original solution of making your first node use `names.get(0)` and your for loop starting at `1` is the ideal solution (in my view, anyway). You need error checking, of course (null list, 0 length list) but you need appropriate error checking no matter what.

Comment: @corsiKa Yeah I left out the error checking code just because I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: @TimmayB answer updated. corsiKa I think you'll find it a better solution design.